# Python : Singleton class object to persist list between imports ? (Like django admin register)

Tags: python, django, function, methods, singleton

I want to have `dict / list` to which I can add values, just like models can be added to the admin register in django !

My attempt : (`package -> __init__.py`)

```
# Singleton object

# __init__.py (Package: pack)
class remember:
  a = []
  def add(data):
    a.append[data]

  def get():
    return a

obj = remember()


# models1.py
import pack

pack.obj.add("data")

# models2.py
import pack

pack.obj.add("data2")
print pack.obj.get()
```

# We should get: ["data", "data2"]
 # We get : ["data2"]

How to achieve the desired functionality ?

Some say that methods can do this if you don't need sub-classing, how to do this with methods ?

**Update:**
To be more clear :

> Just like `django admin register` any one can import and register itself with admin, so that register is persisted between imports.

Comment: I'm really not sure what you're trying to accomplish.  It sounds like you're trying to set up a global variable for some reason.

Comment: I want some sort of global `list` to which values can be added, it should be global and should not get reinitialized on import.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's a singleton you're after, have a look at [this](http://www.garyrobinson.net/2004/03/python_singleto.html) old blog post. It contains a link to a well documented implementation ([here](http://www.garyrobinson.net/singletonmixin.py)).

Answer (score -1):

1. Don't.  If you think you need a global you don't and you should reevaluate how you are approaching the problem because 99% of the time you're doing it wrong.
2. If you have a really good reason to do it perhaps thread_locals() will really solve the problem you're trying to solve.  This allows you to set up thread level global data.  Note:  This is only *slightly* better than a true global and should in general be avoided, and it can cause you a lot of headaches.
3. If you're looking for a cross request "global" then you most likely want to look into storing values in memcached.

Comment: I have to perform a functionality similar to `django admin register` as it maintains a global registry.