# Using Django application with AMQP protocol

Tags: python, django, celery, amqp

I have a web application written Django 1.4. I want process some requests using AMQP(using Rabbitmq) protocol, for that I create an class that create an asynchronous publisher and consumer using pika library, these run in others threads. I want to create a single object of this class and use this in the application.

Searching I found [Python : Singleton class object to persist list between imports ? (Like django admin register)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8207100/python-singleton-class-object-to-persist-list-between-imports-like-django-a), but not work. Also I put the code into the main urls.py and not work. I want some like a grails(java web framework) singleton service or other alternative.

The idea behind is create a comunication completly asynchronous and use the class as middleware between django-celery and the clients. Because I dont want use celery directly from the clients.

Comment: But this is exactly what Celery is already. Why don't you use that?

Comment: The problem is this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24367254/celery-how-to-add-a-callback-function-when-calling-a-remote-task-with-send-tas